# How to debug ValueError with ultra-json loads?

Tags: python-3.x, ujson

I am trying to read a huge json file (9 GB). I switched from json.load to using ultra-json instead with ujson.load in order to speed up the reading of json data, but I keep running into the below ValueError:

```
with open(json_file_path, 'r') as fh:
  data = ujson.loads(fh.read())
ValueError: No ':' found when decoding object value
```

Is this some known issue with ujson? I validated my json and there is no missing ':'

Any suggestions on how to debug this issue or any workarounds to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you validate your JSON file?

Comment: using the standard json tool on linux - the validation ran successfully for the entire json file :                                                          
    python -m json.tool < json_file_path